# Address with zip code. Java

Tags: java

The constructor will throw an IllegalArgumentException exception with the message "Invalid Address Argument" if any parameter is null, or if the zip code has characters others than digits.

The method Character.isDigit can help during the implementation of this method. See the Java API (Character class) for additional information.

I've had the illegal argument exception down. But, not the zip code. Help?

Program.

```
    if(street==null||city==null||state==null){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid Address Argument");
    }

    if(zip == Character.isDigit(ch)){
     //To do??? 

    }
```

Comment: Not a Java expert, but pass in Zip as string and `int intZip = Integer.parseInt(zip)`

Comment: Oh, and I wouldn't throw an exception for `null` arguments, I just wouldn't use them in my address calculation if they aren't provided. But I don't specifically what you're trying to do...

Comment: I assume `zip` is a `String`. Iterate thorugh the `String`'s `char`s (by calling `zip.toCharArray()`) and check each `char` whether it's a digit. If not, do what you have to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try apache stringutils

```
public static boolean isNumeric(CharSequence cs)
Checks if the CharSequence contains only Unicode digits. A decimal point is not a Unicode digit and returns false.

null will return false. An empty CharSequence (length()=0) will return false.

 StringUtils.isNumeric(null)   = false
 StringUtils.isNumeric("")     = false
 StringUtils.isNumeric("  ")   = false
 StringUtils.isNumeric("123")  = true
 StringUtils.isNumeric("12 3") = false
 StringUtils.isNumeric("ab2c") = false
 StringUtils.isNumeric("12-3") = false
 StringUtils.isNumeric("12.3") = false

Parameters:
cs - the CharSequence to check, may be null
Returns:
true if only contains digits, and is non-null
Since:
3.0 Changed signature from isNumeric(String) to isNumeric(CharSequence), 3.0 Changed "" to return false and not true
```

Comment: I rather suspect that this question is a homework assignment, and the student is being asked to *implement a method that does what `StringUtils.isNumeric(...)` does*

Answer (score 0):

```
int zipcode = 0;
try {
     zipcode = Integer.parseInt(zipcode);
}catch (Exception e){}
if (zipcode <= 0)
{
     throw new Exception(..);
}
```

And less than 1,000,000 if you want to be precise. You are using Char which makes no sense as you will have a String.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like homework to me, so I think the first thing you need to do here is learn how to read the documentation.  Let's start by taking your instructor's hint, and looking up the documentation for [`Character.isDigit(char ch)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit(char))

```
public static boolean isDigit(char ch)
```

Handwaving away some of the terms there, the critical things are that the method is `static` (which means we call it like `Character.isDigit(myVariable)` and that it returns a `boolean` (true or false value), and that it accepts a parameter of type `char`.

So, to call this method, we need a `char` (single character).  I'm assuming that your `zip` variable is a `String`.  We know that a string is made up of multiple characters.  So what we need is a way to get those characters, one at a time, from the `String`.  You can find the documentation for the `String` class [here.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

There's a couple of ways to go about it.  We could get the characters in an array using [`toCharArray()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray()), or get a specific character out of the string using [`charAt(int index)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int))

However you want to tackle it, you need to do this (in pseudocode)

```
for each char ch in zip
    if ch is not a digit
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid Address Argument")
```